# Function Pointer, what is the difference between (*f) and f

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers

I have a an array of int and I need to assign a function pointer,

```
f(tab[i]) and (*f)(tab[i])
```

What is the difference between those 2 syntax ??

Comment: I've just discovered dereferencing today, could you give some more information or  could you link me good explanation ??

Comment: Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you have tried?

Comment: Spelling — the `(*f)(tab[i])` notation was mandatory before the C90 standard; the `f(tab[i])` notation was allowed by C90.  The advantage of `(*f)(tab[i])` is that you don't accidentally head off looking for a function `f` — you can see it's a function pointer immediately.  (Of course, that assumes you don't have a colleague who delights in writing `(*sqrt)((*sin)(x)*(*cos)(x))` or other similar absurdities.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks as if you are invoking a function via a function pointer, and you're seeking to pass one element of an array to that function.  The pointer might be defined as:

```
void (*f)(int);     // Function pointer — guessed argument and return types
```

The difference between the invocations `(*f)(tab[i])` and `f(tab[i])` is spelling and history — the result is the same.

The `(*f)(tab[i])` notation was mandatory before the C90 standard; the `f(tab[i])` notation was allowed by C90.  The advantage of `(*f)(tab[i])` is that you don't accidentally head off looking for a function `f` — you can see it's a function pointer immediately.  (Of course, that assumes you don't have a colleague who delights in writing `(*sqrt)((*sin)(x)*(*cos)(x))` or other similar valid but unconscionably obscure absurdities.)

Answer (score 4):

If `tab` is an array of integer, then this below statement

```
(*f)(tab[i])
```

is invoking a function using **function pointer**, where `f` is a **function pointer** which can points to a function which takes argument as `tab[i]`. for e.g In below code block

```
void print_arr(int arr_ele_value) {
        printf("%d\t",arr_ele_value);
}
int main(void) {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5},ele;
        ele = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        void (*f)(int); /* function pointer declaration */
        f = print_arr; /* fun-ptr initialization */
        for(int row = 0; row < ele; row++) {
                (*f)(arr[row]); /* calling a function through function pointer */
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This

```
void (*f)(int);
```

is **function pointer declaration** which says, `f` is a function pointer which can points to a function which takes input argument as `int` and returns `void`.

And here

```
f = function;
```

`f` is assigned with `function` which satisfies above condition of function-pointer declaration.

And this is how you can call a function using function pointer

```
(*f)(arr[row]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference nowadays for the compiler; there is only a difference for the humans.